# SpriteBuilder - how to update Cocos2d

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

It has been awhile since I have used SpriteBuilder with Cocos2d.  I am trying to create a new project from SpriteBuilder that I can modify in Xcode.  From SpriteBuilder I go to 'File > Open Project in Xcode".  This opens Xcode with the new project.  When I build the project I get over 40 errors (e.g. *'UIAccelerometer' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 5.0 - UIAccelerometer has been replaced by the CoreMotion framework.*).  It looks like I need to update my Cocos2d.  So I went to the repo [here](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-objc/blob/v3.4.9/README.md) and found this statement in the README: "SpriteBuilder also allows you to update the Cocos2D version in your project, to newest version, making it trivial to always keep you project updated to latest Cocos2D version."  So it looks like it should be easy to do it, but I can't figure it out.  Any ideas?

```
Xcode Version: 7.1 (7B91b)
SpriteBuilder Version: 1.4.9
SpriteBuilder Revision: eea568a5c7
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you can update cocos2d directly from Spritebuilder, but rather than rely on SpriteBuilder to perform the update, you can do it manually.

You can get the most up to date version of cocos2d by downloading the project straight from its repository on Github. If you want to clone the repository from the command line, the command is:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-objc.git
```

This will download the latest version of Cocos2D (and its dependencies). Now to update the project. Navigate to the new version and copy three folders: cocos2d, cocos2d-ui and external. These three folders contain the changes that need to be moved into your project.

[image: Screenshot of cocos2d folder]

The next part is finding the location of Cocos2D in your project—it's located in the folder named `cocos2d-iphone` inside the project. Pasting the new folders will prompt a warning that you are trying to replace folders that exist already. For the current updated version of cocos2d, this shouldn't be a problem.

Then, you'll want to "Clean" your project and set your iOS Deployment Target to 8.0.

As a safety precaution, you should then clean the project **build folder**. You can find the "Clean Build Folder..." by holding the option key (⌥) while selecting the "Product" drop down. (Note that this is different from just using "Clean".)